# I can't connect from the outside to the mongo-express

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the mongo-express.

Installed on AWS EC2, it was started.

```
$ node app
Mongo Express server listening on port 8081 at localhost
Database connected
Connecting to db...
Database db connected
```

However, it is not possible to connect from the browser to port 8081.

I can download the index.html of the mongo-express using wget command on ec2.

```
$ wget http://admin:pass@localhost:8081
--2016-02-22 02:22:25--  http://admin:*password*@localhost:8081/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="Authorization Required"
Reusing existing connection to localhost:8081.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9319 (9.1K) [text/html]
Saving to: ?index.html?

index.html            0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               GET / 200 218.468 ms - 9319
index.html          100%[===================>]   9.10K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s

2016-02-22 02:22:26 (236 KB/s) - ?index.html? saved [9319/9319]
```

By the way, port 8081 in the security group of ec2 is open to my IP.

Comment: Can you show your code that starts your http listener? Should be something like `app.listen(port, address);`

Comment: There are the following code in the app.js of mongo-express.

`server.listen(config.site.port, config.site.host, function () {`

config.site.port are set as follows in the config.js.

`port: process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8081,`

Comment: What AMI are you using? If it isn't Amazon Linux you may need to play with IPTables

Comment: @FuyuhikoSatou You still aren't giving enough information. What is the value for config.site.host? Is it `localhost` by any chance? I'm guessing you are only binding the listener to local traffic.

Comment: @Max I am using Amazon Linux as AMI.

Comment: @MarkB Lack of information, I am sorry.
Because certainly the value of config.site.host was 'localhost', this was changed to '0.0.0.0', was able to connect. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following settings of config.js is, was the cause

```
site: {    // baseUrl: the URL that mongo express will be located at - Remember to add the forward slash at the stard and end!
baseUrl: '/',
cookieKeyName: 'mongo-express',
cookieSecret:     process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_COOKIESECRET   || 'cookiesecret',
host:             process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST                 || 'localhost',
port:             process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT                 || 8081,
requestSizeLimit: process.env.ME_CONFIG_REQUEST_SIZE        || '50mb',
sessionSecret:    process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SESSIONSECRET  || 'sessionsecret',
sslCert:          process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_CRT_PATH   || '',
sslEnabled:       process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED    || false,
sslKey:           process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_KEY_PATH   || '',
},
```

The value of the host is changed to "0.0.0.0", now to be able to connect from browser to the mongo-express.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've got the issue because I wanted to expose my container on another port (4301).

But the express was still listening on 8081.

To fix it, had to specify indeed `VCAP_APP_HOST` and `VCAP_APP_PORT`.

And you can directly specify it on the run cmd like:

```sh
docker run --network YOUR_NETWORK --name YOUR_MONGO_EXPRESS_CONTAINER_NAME -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=YOUR_MONGO_SERVER_IP -e VCAP_APP_HOST=0.0.0.0 -e VCAP_APP_PORT=4301 -p 4301:4301 mongo-express
```